Error ejecutando la consulta: relation "model_runs" does not exist
Tengo una base de datos en postgre en un volumen de docker. La conexión desde python la consigo hacer correctamente, no tengo problema. El problema viene al intentar hacer una inserción de datos dentro de la tabla statistics.model_runs, la cual no es encontrada:
        self.connection.connect()

        if self.connection.is_connected():
            print('Insertando datos...')
            self.connection.insert(
                "model_runs",
                ['user_id', 'run_at', 'created_at', 'done', 'done_reason', 'eval_count', 'eval_duration', 'load_duration', 'model', 'prompt_eval_count', 'prompt_eval_duration', 'total_duration'], 
                ['1b5e8a58-4a84-43ab-bfb5-91ec1516632b', datetime.now(), created_at, done, done_reason, eval_count, eval_duration, load_duration, model, 0, prompt_eval_duration, total_duration]
            )
            self.connection.disconnect()

Sin embargo, consigo ejecutar una inserción en crudo desde postgresql:
insert into "statistics".model_runs (user_id , run_at , created_at , done, done_reason, eval_count, eval_duration, load_duration, model, prompt_eval_count, prompt_eval_duration, total_duration)
values ('1b5e8a58-4a84-43ab-bfb5-91ec1516632b', now(), now(), true, 'reason', 0, 0, 0, 'model', 0, 0, 0)

¿Qué puede ser lo que está sucediendo?
La definición del insert es la siguiente:
def insert(self, table, columns, values):
        query = sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {table} ({columns}) VALUES ({values})").format(
            table=sql.Identifier(table),
            columns=sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Identifier, columns)),
            values=sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Placeholder() * len(values))
        )
        self.__execute_query(query, values)

def __execute_query(self, query, params=None):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(query, params)
            self.connection.commit()
        except psycopg2.Error as e:
            print(f"Error ejecutando la consulta: {e}")
            self.connection.rollback()

